# In which cases the javascript assigns undefined to undeclared variable and in which throw referenceError when access a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why this evaluate that way (in console)
`console.log(typeof foo); // Output: undefined`
But this another way
`console.log(foo); // Output: ReferenceError: variable is not defined`
Which rule is responsible for this?

In both cases, the "foo" is not declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN docs of `typeof`,
for an undeclared variable the output is `undefined`

> Before ECMAScript 2015, typeof was always guaranteed to return a string for any operand it was supplied with. **Even with undeclared identifiers, typeof will return 'undefined'**. Using typeof could never generate an error.

[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)